# Js push into array which is in an object with multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object like this

```
const tt = {
   a1:[],
   a2:[],
   a3:[],
}
```

Now i want to push an multiple objects from another array into tt based on key's value
for ex:-

```
const task = [
  {id:1, team:[a1,a2]},
  {id:2, team:[a2,a3]},
  {id:3, team:[a1]},
]
```

So now I want an output like this

```
tt = {
  a1:[
    {id:1, team:[a1,a2]},
    {id:3, team:[a1]},
  ],
  a2:[
    {id:1, team:[a1,a2]},
    {id:2, team:[a2,a3]},
  ],
  a3:[
    {id:2, team:[a2,a3]}
  ]
}
```

I tried

```
task.forEach(e => {
  e.team.forEach(t => {
    if (tt[t]) {
      tt[t].push(e);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: shouldn't `{id:1, team:[a1,a2]}` be also part of `tt.a2` ? The question is a bit unclear

Comment: do you want only `a1` and `a2` in the result set?

Comment: what does not work with the code?

Comment: so suppose if i have 10 objects in task array , then for each key in tt 10 array are being pushed

Comment: no, you put the amount of all `team` items. please add the wanted result to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `forEach` loop:

```js
const task = [
  {id:1, team:['a1','a2']},
  {id:2, team:['a2','a3']},
  {id:3, team:['a1']},
]

const res = {
  a1: [],
  a2: [],
  a3: []
}

const keys = Object.keys(res)

task.forEach(item => {
  keys.forEach(k => {
    if (item.team.find(team => team === k)) res[k].push({...item, team: [...item.team]})
  })
})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the loop except the fact that you're not declaring the `task` object in the right way.

With your code it generates an error i.e `ReferenceError: a1 is not defined`. You can fix the error in following ways.

- `const task = [{id:1, team:[tt.a1,tt.a2]}, {id:2, team[tt.a2,tt.a3]}, {id:1, team:[tt.a1]} ]`

  in the above code, we're sending a1, a2 etc. with their reference object i.e `tt`.
- the other way is to declare a1,a2 etc. as strings.

`const task = [{ id: 1, team: ['a1', 'a2'] }, { id: 2, team: ['a2', 'a3'] }`

Here is the code example:

```
const 
  task = [{id: 1, team: ['a1', 'a2']}, {id: 2, team: ['a2', 'a3']}, {id: 3, team: ['a1']}]
  tt = {a1: [], a2: [], a3: []}

task.forEach(task =>
  task.team.forEach(team =>
    tt[team].push(task)
  )
)
```

Comment: forgot to metion it, but values in team array are strings.

Comment: Then what's wrong with the code ? what do you want to ask ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with filter as below. (Guess `a1` in your case is string not variable)

```js
const tt = {
   a1:[],
   a2:[],
   a3:[],
}

const task = [
  {id:1, team:['a1','a2']},
  {id:2, team:['a2','a3']},
  {id:3, team:['a1']},
];

for(const key in tt) {
  tt[key] = task.filter(t => t.team.indexOf(key) >=0);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(tt, null, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

My take

```
const task = [
  {id: 1, team: ['a1', 'a2']},
  {id: 2, team: ['a2', 'a3']},
  {id: 3, team: ['a1']}
]

const tt = {
   a1: [],
   a2: [],
   a3: [],
}

task.forEach(task =>
  task.team.forEach(team =>
    tt[team].push(task)
  )
)
```